# Trouble with parsing a .txt file for specific strings in Python

Tags: python, parsing

I'm having some problems with parsing a log file which is in a .txt format.

Here is a portion of the log where I'm trying to extract the data:

```
CRIT   :  [2013-07-26T14:40:50-0400] msg=<POLICY ADDED>,
```

The specific pieces that I want are the CRIT and msg= POLICY ADDED. The code that I have got so far will find the CRIT string, but not the msg= portion. I believe this has something to do with the whitespace in-between the two words.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

test=open("samhain.txt", "r").readlines()
KEYWORDS= ['CRIT','msg=<POLICY ADDED>']

counterline=[]
counter=0

for line in test:
for word in line.split():
    counter+=1
    if word in KEYWORDS:
        counterline.append(counter)
        print word
```

What do I need to add to my list so that it can deal with the whitespace?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What are you looking to do with this code?

Comment: Yes, the reason you're not returning the second member of KEYWORDS is because `line.split()` is splitting `line` by whitespace. There is no single token 'msg=<POLICY ADDED>'. The regex answer is what you probably want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you could use a regex instead:

```
s = 'CRIT   :  [2013-07-26T14:40:50-0400] msg=<POLICY ADDED>,'    
import re
print re.match(r'(\w+).*?msg=<(.*?)>', s).groups()
# ('CRIT', 'POLICY ADDED')
```